# Unable to parse localhost:27017 with URL

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

i am new with mongodb. i tried to connect my angular based project to mongodb but i get these errors.

MongoRuntimeError: Unable to parse localhost:27017 with URL

TypeError: url_1.URL is not a constructor

the point is i was supposed to install lots of other pachages beside mongodb on my project

```
    "assert": "^2.0.0",
    "browserify-zlib": "^0.2.0",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mongodb": "^5.5.0",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "next-tick": "^1.1.0",
    "node.url": "^1.0.8",
    "os-browserify": "^0.3.0",
    "path-browserify": "^1.0.1",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "querystring-es3": "^0.2.1",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "stream-http": "^3.2.0",
    "timers-browserify": "^2.0.12",
    "tls": "^0.0.1",
    "url": "^0.11.0"
```

and i set these values in my package.json file

```
"browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "dns": false
  }
```

and i was supposed to add this value to ts.config

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "crypto": ["./node_modules/crypto-browserify"],
      "stream": ["./node_modules/stream-browserify"],
      "assert": ["./node_modules/assert"],
      "http": ["./node_modules/stream-http"],
      "https": ["./node_modules/https-browserify"],
      "os": ["./node_modules/os-browserify"],
      "process": ["./node_modules/process"],
      "timers": ["./node_modules/timers-browserify"],
      "url": ["./node_modules/url"],
      "zlib": ["./node_modules/browserify-zlib"],
      "path": ["./node_modules/path-browserify"],
      "querystring":["./node_modules/querystring-es3"]
    }
```

and this to polyfills

import { Buffer } from 'buffer';

```
(window as any).global = window;
global.Buffer = Buffer;
global.process = {
  env: { DEBUG: undefined },
  version: '',
  nextTick: require('next-tick')
} as any;
```

i have no idea why i get this error i ran my code on a a raw project but it is fine
here is my code

```
export class AdaptiveDB {
  uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/bookstore';
  db;
  constructor() {
    this.connectToDb();
  }

  private connectToDb() {
    MongoClient.connect(this.uri, {
      maxPoolSize: 50,
      wtimeoutMS: 2500,
      useNewUrlParser: true
    })
      .then((client) => {
        debugger;
        this.db = client.db();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        debugger;
        console.log('&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&');
        console.log(err);
      });
 }
}
```

please help me

Comment: You can't run a mongo client in a browser

Comment: so how am i supposed to do that? is it even possible?

Comment: No, you literally can't. You need to write sever-side code, either Node.js or any other server-side language.